# Is there an Animal Crossing City Folk face guide?

Tags: animal-crossing-city-folk

Is there an Animal Crossing city folk face guide?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade!  Unfortunately, we don't handle guide requests rather well; they're too generic to be very good.  What you can do, however, is present us with your problem, and we should be able to help you with that.

Comment: You can reword this question to make it more suitable to this site's format. (hint: ask how to achieve a certain face)

Comment: @Frank This is actually a very answerable question. There's only a total of 24 faces and the method of determining them is very straightforward. This wouldn't end up as something like a walkthrough guide or anything like that, it's just a chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your character's face is determined by your answers to Rover's questions and whether your character is male or female. You can see which answers correspond to which faces here: http://nookipedia.com/wiki/Guide:Face_Styles/Animal_Crossing:_City_Folk

Answer (score 1):

In *Animal Crossing: City Folk*, Rover will ask 3 questions on the bus to the new town and your answers to his questions determine your characters eye shape. The eye shape is permanent and it can't be changed, so be sure to look at this [guide](http://www.animalcrossingcommunity.com/accf_face_guide.asp) before you create your character.

Answer (score -1):

Rover will ask 3 questions on the bus and the player's answers will determine the appearance of his/her face/eyes. These are permanent. 
http://accf.wikispaces.com/face+guides